# Issues with subl command for ST3 on OSX (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext3, osx-yosemite

I have Sublime Text 3066 and OS X 10.10.1

I looked through all the relevant questions and responses and followed them all but it still didn't work for me.

After a while, I noticed my $PATH turned into this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I'm not an expert or anything, but the above doesn't look right and no matter what suggestion I follow I keep getting:

```
$ ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `/usr/local/bin` already exists, just run

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
$ hash -r
```

and you should be all set. If the commands above don't work, first run

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
```

then run the commands above.

Finally, just to be obvious, in case it isn't, don't type the `$`, that just signifies the prompt.

Comment: Thank you! But did not work for me. I ran:                            $ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl
rm: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory
$ rm /usr/local/bin/subl
rm: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
mkdir: /usr/local: No such file or directory
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: @atonanon try running `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue today.
I solved it, the problem is that I have been using Tab for folder completion to the `subl` binary. The Tab adds a backslash when there is a space. 
So instead of this:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Do this:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case ST3 did not create `subl` in its `/bin` directory. I am running Yosemite 10.10.3 on MBP. The best way to deal with this is to alias ST3 app to subl, i.e.:

```
# ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.bashrc
subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text'
```

The downside of this solution is it will throw output to the terminal, and the handler trick `>&-` does not work for me. Maybe someone knows how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the other steps weren't working for me. I am running El Capitan, the current latest version. So, I decided to use an alias, and here is what I put in my ~/.bash_profile.

```
alias subl='/Applications/SublimeText.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
```

Don't forget to source the ~/.bash_profile once you are done editing it.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can use subl as you normally would.